# Android Wrong selected dimen

Tags: android, dimensions

I have the folder: values (represents xxhdpi). Create inside dimens.xml with the respect values. Tested the app in an xxhdpi device and works great.

Then I create a values-xxxhdpi with their dimens.xml file. The problem is that when I test again with an xxhdpi device, is taking the values from dimens in values-xxxhdpi folder and not in the values (default) folder.

With xhdpi happens the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you named the folders wrong.

Try `values` instead of `value`.

So try `values-xxhdpi`and `values-xxxhdpi`for the names of the folders.

Comment: Sorry i edited de question, i have values folder. I don't have a values-xxhdpi, I have only values and values-xxxhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your device runs on xxxhdpi?

xxxhdpi is defined as shown below:

- mdpi     379.00 x 379.00 px
- tvdpi    504.54 x 504.54 px
- hdpi     568.50 x 568.50 px
- xhdpi    758.00 x 758.00 px
- xxhdpi   1137.00 x 1137.00 px
- xxxhdpi  1516.00 x 1516.00 px

So maybe you have to check your resolution like:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
bld.append(String.format("Height: %s %s", dpHeight, System.getProperty("line.separator")));
bld.append(String.format("Width:  %s %s", dpWidth, System.getProperty("line.separator")));

String densityType = "";
switch (displayMetrics.densityDpi)
{
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        densityType = "LDPI";
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        densityType = "MDPI";
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        densityType = "HDPI";
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
        densityType = "XHDPI";
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
        densityType = "XXHDPI";
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
        densityType = "XXXHDPI";
        break;
}

bld.append(String.format("Density:  %s %s(%s dpi)", displayMetrics.density, densityType, displayMetrics.densityDpi));
txtScreenInfo.setText(bld.toString());
```